# Fireball commands stopped working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I made a Minecraft command block "spell" that summons fireballs in 5 directions around the player closest to me and close in on that player. I got it working, but then one day it just stopped.

The basic command I used for the fireballs:

```
execute @p[name=Sydengiss] ~ ~ ~ @p[r=25,team=NonSpellcaster] ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~3 ~1.5 ~ {ExplosionPower=0,direction:[-4.0,-0.5,0.0]
```

I set everyone but me on the "NonSpellcaster" team.

Answer (score 3):

The NBT syntax is incorrect; you have an equals sign when instead you should have a colon. The correct tag is `ExplosionPower` (as tags are case-sensitive):

```
/execute @p[name=Sydengiss] ~ ~ ~ @p[r=25,team=NonSpellcaster] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~3 ~1.5 ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[-4.0,-0.5,0.0]}
```

Comment: Whoops, I simply typed it in wrong on the question